# RichTextArea displaying out of the pdf

Tags: apex, visualforce, pdf

In RichTextArea field i have content with different style format. After generating the pdf, the content is not displaying correctly. It text cutting at the right border. If i remove the different styled text from richtextarea, then pdf displaying correctly. 
styled content be like in image
[image]

crossed in pdf 
[image]

I am used the below code for break the lines and display in pdf...

```
Integer maxLen = 85;
        if (source != null) {
            for (String part : source.split('<[\\w\\s\\.\'-=:;"&\\?/]+>|\\s')) {
                if (part.length() > maxLen) {
                    source = source.replace(part, part.substring(0, maxLen) + ' ' + part.substring(maxLen, part.length()));
                    return breakLongLines(source);
                }
            }
        }
```